# Math.Net Numerics Matrix Market

Tags: c#

I want to use Math.Net for reading and reexporting of a matrix. Therefore, I am using Numerics.Data.Text

When I use MatrixMarketReader. ReadMatrix(path), the compiler throws the error:

> ReadMatrix is not supported by the language

though it should be.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that you have all relevant using statements....

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please paste your code that you are using so we can be able to help you.

Comment: Number of operations supported by C# *language* is very small - basic math (+,/,-,*) on basic numeric types, adding strings, and comparisons (==, !=, <=, =>). You should be not be expecting that some random operations "is supported by the language".

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using assemblies for different .Net versions. Check that your main project and the assembly containing `MatrixMarketReader` target the same or compatible .Net version.

Comment: Boris, that was exactly the reason why it didn't work. I was using an older version of Math.Net while I used an actual version of the MathNet.Numerics.Data package. Thanks a lot!